# Weird box-shadow bug in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I'm having some really weird bug with box-shadow and text-shadow Android Chrome. Chrome on my desktop works fine, but on Android, it shows a weird shadow effect. Take a look at this screenshot to better understand what's going on:

[image]

As you can see, Chrome on Android are rendering the both text-shadow and box-shadow in a different way. Here's an example of the code I'm using for the *Menu* label and the hamburger menu:

```
#menu-toggle{
    position: fixed;
    top: 17px;
    right: 13px;
    z-index: 120;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Katahdin Round',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
}
#menu-toggle .bottom, #menu-toggle .middle, #menu-toggle .top{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 21px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
            box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
}
```

Has anyone have saw this kind of bug? Is there any workaround for this one?

One observation: the logo at the left is an svg graphic. It uses an svg filter to do the box-shadow on it.

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Yes, i can see this bug in my phone as well. the bug is because of box shadow. i have similar bug in our app on android, hence how i arrived at your question. look in the photo below and you will see a weird stepping of the box shadow above the bar in bottom of app screen http://s23.postimg.org/byzouu8cb/Screenshot_2016_01_08_02_40_41.png

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread but finally, I got a fix for this issue.

This is the correct way to put a box shadow with CSS. It takes 6 values inset can be left optional.

```
box-shadow: horizontal vertical blur spread color inset;
```

I know that blur and spread are optional but in few browsers, they require that value.

A simple example so that it works in all browsers.

```
target {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(17,17,17,.3);
}
```

The same thing applies for the text-shadow. This worked for me hope works for you as well.